# Objective-C add UIBarButtonItem to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add an UIBarButtonItem and an UIViewController with the following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"back", @"")
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(goBack)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

But when I run my app, the UIBarButtonItem does not appear. Please Help.

Comment: Is your view controller in a navigation controller? The `navigationItem` only appears if the view controller is in a navigation controller.

Comment: Try this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32983383/988169

Answer (score 0):

Before you localize your string, make sure it works with a regular string. So then you know if the code for the button is incorrect or the if you didn't set up your localized string properly.

Comment: I would try this as well. I would assume your localized string is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your view controller into navigation controller at that time so can find the UIBarButtonItem. Because it is navigation item you need to embed inside the navigation controller.